# Lost profile on Xbox 360 without Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360

My husband was playing COD Ghosts this past weekend. When he turned the XBox 360 on the next day all of our profiles were gone. In memory, we can see 2 saved COD games but they say "unassigned profiles" underneath. We do not play online and are not connected to XBox Live as we don't have WiFi in the house. Any suggestions?

Comment: Get a router and get Xbox Live subscriptions?

Comment: I'm sorry if that came off as disrespectful or rude, but to ensure everything is saved, I personally would do this